# How to calculate integrals in Ideal Fermi Gas theory?

Tags: thermodynamics, integration, ideal-gas, many-body

I'm having troubles solving integrals in the Ideal Fermi Gas theory.
In particular the ones of the type:

$$ 
 \int\frac{d\vec{k}}{(2π)^3}θ(k_F − k)( \vec{k} \cdot \vec{q})^n$$

but I actually don't understand how to do all types of integrals in the theory, and can't find a good reference explaining it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the other answer, we can take $\mathbf{q}$ to point in the $z$-direction:
$$\int \frac{d^3k}{(2\pi)^3} \theta(k_F - k)(\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{q})^n = 
\int d\Omega\int_{0}^{k_F}\frac{dkk^2}{8 \pi^3} (kq\cos{\theta})^n$$

$$=\frac{q^n}{4\pi^2}\int_{-1}^{1}\cos^n\theta ~d(\cos\theta)\int_{0}^{k_F}k^{n+2}dk$$

$$=\frac{q^n [1+(-1)^n]}{4\pi^2(n+1)(n+3)}k_F^{n+3}$$

Answer (score -1):

The integral is spherically symmetric so we can put $\mathbf{q}$ along the $z$-axis:
$$\int \frac{d^3k}{(2\pi)^3} \theta(k_F - k)(\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{q})^n = 
\int d\Omega\int_{0}^{k_F}\frac{k^2dk}{8 \pi^3} (kq\cos{\theta})^n$$
the integral then factorizes
$$\frac{q^n}{4\pi^2}\int_{-1}^{1}\cos^n\theta ~d(\cos\theta)\int_{0}^{k_F}k^{n+2}dk$$
which is simply
$$\frac{q^n [1+(-1)^n]}{4\pi^2(n+1)^2}k_F^{n+3}$$

Comment: While the sentiment is correct, the final result is wrong. For example, if n=2, you will expect the result is proportional to $k_F^5$ not $k_F^3$. You dropped the $k^2$ that should be next to the $dk$ on the RHS of the first equality.

Comment: This final result should be: $\frac{q^n [1+(-1)^n]}{4\pi^2(n+1)(n+3)}k_F^{n+3}$

Comment: @hft so where does the $k^2$ comes from?

Comment: @GabrieleGarofalo it comes from $d^3 k = d\Omega dk k^2$. The usual 3D volume element written in spherical coordinates (in k space). You wrote the volume element in your post as $\vec{dk}$.

Comment: @GabrieleGarofalo This is fairly basic. And not a physics question. If you are confused about this, the reference you should find is an elementary vector calculus textbook.

Comment: I see that was indeed basic. What disoriented me was a sentence in Fetter-Walecka, talking about some sort of mean of $k^2$ over the Fermi distribution.

Comment: My bad, I wrote this before bed xd